# Queries in cloud firestore and requests

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, python-requests, querying

Is it possible to use requests library to querying data from cloud firestore?
For example this is how database look like:[image: database]:

I tried to get data(get all documents where "add_date" is equal to "01.08.2020" and limit these to 3):

```
result = requests.get('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**************************maindata/.json?orderBy="add_date"&EqualTo="01.01.2020"&limitToLast=3')
```

but I am getting error:

> {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "limitToLast": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'limitToLast' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "EqualTo": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'EqualTo' could not be found in request message.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "limitToLast": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'limitToLast' could not be found in request message.'}, {'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "EqualTo": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'EqualTo' could not be found in request message.'}]}]}}

For realtime database that was okay.

I know that the problem is much more complicated but I don't know where to start to solve it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Firestore has a REST API.  It's different than Realtime Database.  Without seeing the details of what you sent, it's not possible for us to see where you went wrong.

Comment: I edited my post to show my problem better.

Comment: You can't use the Realtime Database API to query Firestore.  They have completely different APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realtime Database and Firestore are two different products, although both are available in Firebase. Ex. Firestore is available also on Google Cloud Console, while Realtime Database is not. Please take a look at this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) for more details.

So if they are completely different products, it's hard to imagine that they will work on the same API's.

I suppose that you have created example request with [this Realtime Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database). This of course will not work with Firestore. There is an equivalent [API for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents)  which is much more complicated. This is not very surprising as Firestore is designed for more advance use.

So if you asking for starting point I suggest to get familiar with the API and try to play with it. I hope it will help! Good luck!